# Executing mvn tests using gitlab yml

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I want to execute my tests under an automation framework (selenium + cucumber BDD) built with maven. I have a test stage for this and other stages in my pipeline. Test stage is shown below:

```
test_regression_suite:
  stage: test_regression_suite
  tags:
    - ci
  script:
    - Start-Process powershell.exe "-Command Set-Location -Path 'C:\Users\path_to_my_test_framework'; mvn test --debug"
  allow_failure: true
```

I am using Gitlab runner (tags: ci) to execute my pipeline. This runner is hosted in my VM and configured with my Gitlab repository. Test framework and all necessary files are there in place under the VM.

mvn test command works when I execute it with cmd or with PowerShell.

**Problem:**
This stage runs successfully/ passed but tests are not getting executed (no logs are generated in test reports and it shows previous execution logs which I ran manually). When I try to run this command under the "script" tag in my stage manually, it runs fine and executes the test cases which I can observe and see the logs for but it does not runs via the pipeline.

Any possible suggestion here what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get a maven log that can give you more information?

Comment: Not really. I am able to execute it manually but it is not working using the CICD gitlab runner.